# Unable to horizontally align the links and the logo in the nav bar

Tags: html, css, nav

I am trying to horizontally align the logo and the links but for some reason it is getting stacked up as shown in the image below.

[image: screenshot of the nav bar]

Please could someone help me?

I have included all of CSS below.

```css
body {
    font-family: Apercu, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: black;
    background-color: floralwhite;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 32em) {
    header {
        top: 2em;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding-right: 2em;
        padding-left: 2em;
    }
}

header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}

header h1 {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: black;
}

header nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-right: 1.25em;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}

header a,
h1 {
    text-decoration: none;
}

header nav {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html">
            <h1>Alokananda Y</h1>
        </a>
        <nav>
            <a href="">One</a>
            <a href="">Two</a>
            <a href="">Three</a>
            <a href="">Your Choice</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
        <h2>Favorite Foods</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Rice</li>
            <li>Beans</li>
            <li>Vegetables</li>
            <li>Fruits</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</body>
```

I have been trying to follow this post [Aligning Logo and Nav Links Horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744453/aligning-logo-and-nav-links-horizontally) but unable to get it right.

Comment: what should be output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `position:absolute` than you have to give spacing to body as your total header height.
With `position:absolute` update the css

```html
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 82px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;    
}
header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;   
}
header nav {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
}
```

**Or** 
 Remove the position styles from header and add the style to nav

```html
header {
    padding: 1em;
}
header nav {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
}
```